# Is $p \lor (q \land r)\equiv p \land (q \lor r)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Before writing, I'm not good at English. As I developed the law of distribution, I felt strange.

$$\begin{align}
p \land (q \lor r)& \equiv (p \land q) \lor (p \land r)\\
&\equiv X \lor (p\land r)\tag{$X=p \land q$}\\
&\equiv (X \lor p) \land (X \lor r)\\
&\equiv [(p \land q) \lor p] \land [(p \land q) \lor r]\\
&\equiv (p \lor p) \land (p \lor q) \land (p \lor r) \land (q \lor r)\\
&\equiv p \land (q \lor r) \land (p \lor q) \land (p \lor r)\\
&\equiv [p \land (q \lor r)] \land p \lor (q \land r)\end{align}
$$

When called $p \land (q \lor r)=A,\ p \lor (q \land r)=B.$
I have never heard of $A≡A \land B$. (When they are not the same)
So I developed $p \lor (q \land r)$

$$\begin{align}
p \lor (q \land r) &\equiv (p \lor q) \land (p \lor r)\\
&\equiv Y \land (p \lor r)\ \ \ \ (let\ Y=p \lor q)\\
&\equiv (Y \land p) \lor (Y \land r)\\
&\equiv [(p \lor q) \land p] \lor [(p \lor q) \land r]\\
&\equiv (p \land p) \lor (p \land q) \lor (p \land r) \lor (q \land r)\\
&\equiv [p \lor (q \land r)] \lor [p \land (q \lor r)]\end{align}
$$

$A\equiv A \land B,\ B\equiv A \lor B$

I don't know if they are equal or if I made a mistake.

Comment: They are not equivalent; check with truth table.

Comment: If $p$ is false while $q$ and $r$ are both true then the first statement is true while the second statement is false.

Comment: "$p$ or ($q$ and $r$)" can true when $p$ is false (ir $q$ and $r$ are both true.  But "$p$ and ($q$ or $r$)" *must* have $p$ be true to true.  So they can not be equivalent.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You mistake is:  $A \equiv (A$ and $B)$ does not mean $A \equiv B$.  It means $B \to A$.

Comment: so $(p\lor(q\land r))\to (p\land(q\lor r))$ and $ (p\lor(q\land r))\equiv  (p\lor(q\land r))\land (p\land(q\lor r))$ but that does *not* mean $(p\lor(q\land r))\equiv (p\land(q\lor r))$ as it is possible for $(p\land(q\land r))$ to be false while $(p\lor(q\land r))$ is true.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing can be easier to understand if you produce a real-world example.  On paper, $p\lor(q\land r)$ is just abstract symbols.  But when you translate it into something practical, a different part of your brain can work on it in a different way.

Our brains are good at thinking about social rules.  So let's imagine that you live in a place where a person is allowed to drink alcohol in a restaurant if:

- they are over the age of 18 ($p$), OR
- their parent is present ($q$) AND their parent gives permission ($r$).

This rule is $p\lor(q\land r)$ and seems plausible.

Now let's see if $p\land(q\lor r)$ is the same thing.  This new rule says that a person is allowed to drink alcohol in a restaurant if

1. they are over the age of 18 ($p$) AND
2. their parent is present ($q$) OR has given permission ($r$)

This means that even a 60-year-old customer must get permission from their 80-year-old parent.  Or, if they can't get permission, they have to bring their parent into the restaurant.

Perhaps it is clear that, while the original rule was reasonable, this second rule is absurd.  If so, it should be clear that the two rules can't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

$p \vee (q \wedge r)$ and $p \wedge (q \vee r)$ are *not* equivalent. For instance, let $p$, $q$, $r$ be the statements
$$
\begin{aligned}
p\colon \quad \text{$0 < 1\phantom{.}$}\\
q\colon \quad \text{$1 < 0\phantom{.}$}\\
r\colon \quad \text{$2 < 0.$}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $q$ and $r$ are false, both $q \wedge r$ and $q \vee r$ are false.

But then since $p$ is true, $p \vee (q \wedge r)$ is true while $p \wedge (q \vee r)$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

At first you make a mistake in third rows from down to up.

Then it's true that in general $A \equiv A \land B$ isn't true for independent $A,B$.

But in your case they are dependent in value!

Answer (score 1):

Consider when $p$ is true but both $q$ and $r$ are false.
[Here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(p%E2%88%A8(q%E2%88%A7r))%E2%86%94(p%E2%88%A7(q%E2%88%A8r))) is a link to a useful online tool.

Comment: thanks. It seems to be a useful tool.

Comment: You're welcome, @이규헌 :)

Answer (score 0):

$p$ or ($q$ and $r$) is obviously not equivalent to $p$ and ($q$ or $r$).

$p = FALSE; q=TRUE;r=TRUE$ will make $p$ or ($q$ and $r$)= TRUE but $p$ and ($q$ or $r$)=FALSE.  (This is clear as [$p$ AND M] *requires* $p$ to be true but [$p$ OR K]$ does not.

When yous said $A = p$ or ($q$ and $r$)$ and $B = p$ and ($q$ or $r$).  The $A$ and $B$ are *NOT* independent.

Notice that $B\implies A$.  It is not possible for $B$ to be true and $A$ to be false.  But for all *other* cases $A$ and ($A$ and $B$) have the same truth values.

If you have $B\implies A$ then, yes, $A$ and ($A$ and $B$) have the same truth values.

If you discover that  $[A] \equiv [A] \land [B]$, you can not conclude $[A] \equiv [B]$.  What you *can* conlclude is that $[B] \implies [A]$

So, no,  $p\lor (q \land r) \not \equiv p\land(q\lor r)$

But $p\land(q\lor r) \implies p\lor (q \land r)$

Comment: I understand.Then where is the end if we can develop the law of distribution infinitely?

Comment: What end?  What law of distribution?

Comment: p or (q and r)≡(p or q) and (q or r)≡(p or q and r) or (p and q or r)≡ ...≡It seems to be different from the law of distribution in numbers. If we can develop indefinitely, how far should we call it development?

Comment: Theres nothing deep to this.  $A \land B \implies A\lor B$ and if $B\implies A$ then $B \equiv B \land A$ and $A \equiv A\lor B$.  That's all this is.  So $A \equiv A \lor (A\land $ John likes cotton candy$)$.  There's nothing deep about this.  It's just telescoping.